# klish command completion on pressing tab button

Tags: clish

Hi I have small doubt in klish xml file. I implemented a small xml file for klish

```
<COMMAND name="show core"
         help="It will show core status"
  <ACTION> echo "core status"  </ACTION>
  </COMMAND>
```

I thought that by using command "show core" on klish command line it will print the core status as output but I am not able to print core status on command line of klish
How to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not use space in the **< COMMAND >** tag like in my case I used.

```
<COMMAND name="show core">
```

This is not the proper way to use space in the  **< COMMAND >** tag

But if you want that your command should be like this only i.e. **show core** then there are two ways to achieve it.

First way:-

```
<COMMAND name="show"
         help="Put what help you want to give"/>
<COMMAND name="show core"
         help="Put what help you want to give">
      <DETAIL>   
      </DETAIL>
 <ACTION>echo "core status"</ACTION>
</COMMAND>
```

Second way:- Use **VAR** tag and **completion** attribute in  **PARAM** tag

```
<COMMAND name="show"
         help="Put what help you want to give">
   <PARAM name="pname"
          help="Put what help you want to give"
          ptype="STRING"
          completion="${vartagvariable}"/>
    <DETAIL> 
    </DETAIL>
   <ACTION>echo "core status"</ACTION>
  <VAR name="vartagvariable" help="Something...." value="core" />
 </COMMAND>
```