# How to complete a command by pressing tab button in klish

Tags: clish

I am working on klish xml files. How should I autocomplete a command on klish. Please answer it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing with the same problem but any how I resolved this problem. For completing an command in klish there are two ways. 
Here is a link of both ways to complete a command in clish
[klish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581815/klish-command-completion-on-pressing-tab-button)

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks @vivek. That's what I was looking for.